# How to load csv file data to CDH?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, bigdata

I have multiple csv files and I want to import them to CDH tables. I want to know if there is any tools like sqoop to import data from files. Is there any way or tool to do it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Hue Web UI.

Upload file to hdfs with FileBrowser Menu.

After that you can use Data Browsers / Metastore Tables

Create new schema / create new table with uploaded files.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way is:

```
CREATE TABLE Something (id int, name string, salary double, ....) row format delimited fields terminated by ‘,’;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/yourcsvfile.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE Something;
```

Comment: 1. Don't I need to load file to hdfs?

Comment: 2. Will this load all data correctly (I have int, string, timestamp)?

Comment: 3. I have more than one file. Should I only repeat 2nd command?

Comment: 4. Should I use impala or hive?